# How to convert to Date in Java Script?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

```
console.log(json[0].aDate);    //Mar 4 ,2022 10 30 PM
const date = new Date(json[0].aDate); // Date{NaN}
const date = moment(json[0].aDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'); // Invailed Date
```

Is there any other way?

I've tried `new Date()`, `moment.js` and `moment()`,`format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')` but that doesn't work.

I expect the following result:
`console(date) //'2022-3-4 10:30:SS'`

Comment: Your original date string format (Mar 4 ,2022 10 30 PM) in `json[0].aDate` is not valid for Date. You may need to use `substring()` to extract correct information and reform a valid date string before apply into `new Date()` or `moment()`.

Comment: @kiuQ Are you saying to sort by substring first and then use new date or moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an simple example to convert your date string (Mar 4 ,2022 10 30 PM) into date object.

I would use `split()` function to extract the information in date string.

Be careful about the time generated in js `Date()`, it uses UTC time.

```
let monthArray = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

//Extract datetime information
let date = "Mar 4 ,2022 10 30 PM";
date = date.split(' ');

let year = date[2].replace(',', '');
let month = monthArray.findIndex(m => m == date[0]);  //javascript month is start from 0 to 11
let day = date[1];

let hour = Number(date[3]); //Prevent string appending
if(date[5] == "PM" && hour != 12){
    //Handle convertion from 12-hour to 24-hour
    hour += 12;
}
let minute = date[4];
let second = 0;

// Fri Mar 04 2022 22:30:00
console.log(new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second));

//2022-03-04T22:30:00.000Z
console.log(new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second).toISOString());
```